# How to remove a commit from the middle of a branch

Tags: git, git-commit

I've made some commits and have pushed it to my remote repo. One of those I want to remove. It includes only one binary file, which was changed only in that commit in that branch. How to remove it without harm for later commits?

Comment: `git rebase -i TARGET_COMMIT~1` and then don't pick `TARGET_COMMIT` I think would work.

Comment: In @CollinD solution, you will have to force your push to remote repository (preferred `--force-with-lease`), because your changes won't be possible to fast-forward.
If you want to avoid those issues, you can `git revert` this commit.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `interactive (-i) rebase` to remove a previous commit.

```
$ git log                          # copy the target commit 

$ git rebase -i <target-commit>~1  # start rebase from the previous commit of target commit
```

An editor will open with a list of commits, one per line. Each of these lines begins with `pick`. **Comment out your target commit's line** (Put `#` at the start of target commit line).

OR, put `drop` or `d` instead of commenting out the line with **`#`**.

```
$ git rebase --continue      # repeat the command until finish rebase
```

Now, you need to do force (-f) push to remote since git history has been changed!

```
$ git push -f origin HEAD
```

Comment: What will happen after the last step i.e push -f ??

Comment: @AKSHAYSHINGOTE your remote (`origin` here) will be updated (removed the commit from git history).

Comment: Nailed it, thanks for this. **NOTE: If you want to be more explicit, you can also use `drop` or `d` instead of commenting out the line with `#`.**

Comment: Yes, that's right @joshu Pinter. Updated answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is there an alternative that doesn't involve force push, and records this commit "deletion"?

Comment: @tejasvi88 to delete a commit is like changing git history so, there is no alternative way except force push! (so far I know)

Comment: Why no one talk about flag --rebase-merges ?
It should be considered in answer, becasuse this solution will remove merge commit between HEAD and target commit+1

Answer (score 12):

The flag [--rebase-merges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---preserve-merges) should be considered in answer, because the accepted solution will remove the merge commit between HEAD and target commit~1

Example:

> **Before any rebase:**
>
> ```
> f3e07b4 (HEAD -> dev, origin/dev) headCommit
> dd3d182 Merged PR 425: added playoutServerUsage
> 7ed3eb5 added playoutServerUsage
> 03b52af feat: add Description Series  #targetCommit
> 0a1217c some_older_commit
> ```

> **git rebase -i target-commit~1**
>
> ```
> c11fa07 (HEAD -> dev) headCommit
> 7ed3eb5 added playoutServerUsage
> 0a1217c some_older_commit
> ```

> **git rebase -i target-commit~1 --rebase-merge**
>
> ```
> a1943b6 (HEAD -> dev) headCommit
> 12411a1 Merged PR 425: added playoutServerUsage
> 7ed3eb5 added playoutServerUsage
> 0a1217c some_older_commit
> ```
>
> Rebase with flag --rebase-merges can be harder and whole process will be longer (bigger tree), but still we have to
> locate target commit and change *'pick'* to *'drop'*

After that, I would recommend using

```
git push --force-with-lease origin HEAD
```

instead of force only.

[force vs force-with-lease](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823692/git-push-force-with-lease-vs-force/52937476#52937476)

PS. It is worth paying attention to which commits hashes was changed

Answer (score -3):

If untracking all the files is okay with you, then you can try deleting the `.git` file from the directory.
This files contains all the details regarding all the git commits.

It worked for me and may also work for you.