# How to remove a previous commit in git from repository?

Tags: git

`git` keeps previous commits in the repo. I want to know how I can remove a specific commit (I have its ID) from my repo history further?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing commit from middle of a branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42518104/removing-commit-from-middle-of-a-branch)

Comment: Can anyone please explain me that ?? I didn't get that

Answer (score 0):

As explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/42522493/1507546, you can use `git rebase`

```
 # 06c8c77^ means the commit just before 06c8c77
 git rebase -i 06c8c77^

 # Your default editor configured for git will be opened with line similar to the following
```

In the first part you'll see many commits, the one you want to remove is at the bottom, you can compare the commit hash for that.

```
pick 91c0bd0 track one
....
pick 06c8c77 bla bla bla # the one to remove
```

To remove it, and as explain in the second part, all you need to do is to remove the line from the editor.

```
# ....
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
```

After that you should save and exit your editor. If this goes without error, you need to update the remote branch. If your branch's name is `feature/my_branch` for instance, you need to do the following:

```
git push -f origin feature/my_branch # -f or --force to replace the remote feature/my_branch with the local one
```

N.B. This is safe as long as the branch is only used by a single developer when `rebase` is used.