# Git replace the local branch and rebase my branch on top of the new one

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I am pretty sure the answer to this question may be found on SO, at least in bits and pieces on several different posts. I have a branch that was created of a different branch. I have made some commits in my branch and then the owner of the other branch has force pushed some commits onto my branch. After that happened, I have made a few more commits.

Now I am asked to get his clean version (by which I think he meant to replace my local branch) and then rebase my branch on top of the new branch (his?) so that his commits (the "force-pushed" ones) will go away. By that I think what he wants is to never see his commits in the history of my branch.

What would be the steps to do this? I found a lot of references to

```
git fetch
git reset --hard @{u}
git rebase -i origin/master
```

but not sure of the outcome as I don't seem to be able to get rid of his commits. For anyone needing a visual picture of what I am talking about, here it is:

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am using Git Bash, btw.

TIA,
Ed

Edit: as requested, here is the output of the "git log --graph --oneline --all" command (Sorry, I had to cover all the comments as some may contain sensitive info):

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, it sounds like it should be a fairly straightforward interactive rebase, dropping the unwanted commits. Likely just `git rebase -i FIRST_COMMIT_TO_REMOVE~`, and mark the offending commits as `drop`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42522493

Comment: @Hasturkun Thanks for your suggestion. See my second comment to Nikola. I need to get rid of the commits but preserve the code changes contained within.

Comment: If you want to preserve his changes, you can `squash` or `fixup` to unify these into a new commit (Though I have to say, your intention is somewhat unclear, It sounded like you want these removed from history, which implies that they won't exist). I'll mention in advance that you also have the option of reordering commits, if the intention is to have his commits happen after yours (or the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

One tip, post the output of `git log --graph --oneline --all` with your HEAD, so we have a better insight on what is going on.

If I understood correctly, you should try the following: (make sure you don't force push something. Use hash codes for arguments on `reset`)

`git reset his-last-commit` (to uncommit recent edits after his commits)

`git stash` (to save them)

`git reset --hard your-commit` (this deletes his commits)

`git stash pop` (this applies your recent edits on top)

If this doesn't work, you should try `git cherry-pick`

Comment: Which one is my "your-commit" in the "git reset --hard your-commit" command? Would it be my last commit before he added his 4 commits? Also, if it is my last commit before he added his stuff, wouldn't this "reset --hard" cause his changes to be lost?

Comment: "By that I think what he wants is to never see his commits in the history of my branch." Doesn't that mean it was supposed to lose his changes?

Comment: No, he does not want to lose his changes, as they are important. He just wants those 4 commits to go away from the history of the branch. He did mention that what he wants can be achieved with a rebase, so maybe the suggestion @Hasturkun has made makes sense